# 2nd floor tub and toilet draining fine ,sink clogged trap is clear,snaked clear and clogged again after a day?

Tags: plumbing

I have a 2 story older cape home.
have had issues with 2nd floor tub drain in the past. always able to correct it by snaking.
Now the sink drain has an issue.clogged.
no tub gurgling tub drains fine.
I have tried everything .
removed all sink piping and snaked from wall up the vent and down drain 10' finally got hot water hose water to flow great down the line.
put all back together was good for a day , then had the same issue again??
can you help?

Comment: Snake it again. you probably loosened the obstruction and it traveled down the pipe and jammed up at the next bend.

Comment: What type of plumbing are your drain lines? If it's galvanized, they tend to behave like our veins like when we get a cholesterol build up. Over time a hardened partial blockage can happen and the opening will get smaller and smaller. If it' ABS, causes for that can be very different.